# AsyncServerStreamingCall and failed authentication

Tags: c#, grpc

I have .Net 5 console client calling a service using gRPC and opening a bi-directional channel.

The code all works fine when I pass headers (the server is set up for Auth), but I am interested in seeing what happens when bad/no credentials are passed. I see on the server a 401 message as the call is not authenticated, but there is no indication of failure in the client, it just hangs.

The following works just fine, where `response` is `AsyncServerStreamingCall<GetResponse>`

```
response = client.GetSomeMethod(
    new GetRequest
    {
         Parameter1 = args[0],
    },
    headers);
```

when I take the headers out, I still get back a response, but when I await the `ResponseStream` it just hangs.

```
var monitorTask = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await foreach (var result in response.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync())
                {
                    this.Results.Add(result);
```

In the working case, this simply blocks until the first result is streamed back by the server. In the not-working case, it just blocks.

How do I detect that the call to the server failed? Should I be seeing an exception or should I be checking a status field somewhere?

Comment: If server is returning a status 401 in the response you need to handle the response in your controller.  Not Found is one type of http error code.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling?force_isolation=true#httperror

Comment: Hi @jdweng - which controller? I have edited the question to make it clear that the client calling the gRPC service is a console app. My controller action (gRPC service method) is not called as the incoming request is not authenticated.

Comment: Search the entire link for "HttpResponseMessage".  I can't tell right now if gRPC is not return anything or the issue is in your controller.  When you get an HTTP error you do not get the ACTION message in the body of the response.  So your controller has to be able to handle the exception that is caused by the missing ACTION and instead report the status error.  When the controller is processing a response it is doing a deserialization of the response ACTION.  So you may be ignoring the deserialization Exception or waiting for a good Action response.